# distinct values using LINQ

Tags: linq, select, linq-to-sql, dropdown

I try to get distinct values in LINQ i try this for this first i create method and then i call this method on page load and assign

```
regiondrop.DataSource = getregion();
regiondrop.DataSourc=DataTextField="Region"
regiondrop.DataSourc==DataTextField="RID"


 private List<tab1> getregion()
        {
            using (T1 tee = new T1())
            {
            var tempList = tee.tbl1.ToList();
            var list = (from ta in tempList
            select new { ta.Region, ta.RID }).Select(x => new tbl1
            {
             Id = x.RID,
             reg=x.Region
             }).ToList();
            return list;
            }

        }
```

Data in db like this

```
RID Region
1   Canada
2   UK
3  London
4  Paris
5  UK
6  Brazil
7  London
```

Data in drop-down like this

```
Canada
UK
London
Paris
UK
Brazil
London
```

but i want data like this

```
Canada
UK
London
Paris
Brazil
```

any solution?

Comment: You could use `List<T>.Distinct()` with a custom comparator on `Region` property. ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb920306%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `GroupBy`

```
var list =  from ta in tempList
            group ta by ta.Region into g
            select g.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: and will i omit this or not?select new { ta.Region, ta.RID }).Select(x => new tbl1
            {
             Id = x.RID,
             reg=x.Region
             }).ToList()

Comment: hi.. when i try like this ..  private List<tblRegion_Uni> getregion()
            {
                using (TrackDataEntities1 tee = new TrackDataEntities1())
                {
                    var tempList = tee.tblRegion_Uni.ToList();

                    var list = (from ta in tempList
                                group ta by ta.Region into g
                                select new { g.Key });
                    return list;
                }

            }

Comment: this shows same output. repeated values in dropdown

Comment: Are you binding on the correct list? debug the list.

Comment: yes when i set breakpoint then there is data in list

Comment: tempList  and list data is same when i check like 7 records in tempList  and 7 records in list

Comment: @SUPER_USER i have changed the code, have you tried it?

Comment: yes this work thank